# The idea of the transverse to a vector field

Tags: general-topology, geometry, vector-spaces

I have a quick question. I am independently reading a book on three dimensional geometry and topology. One line has been stumping me. Here is the following paragraph I do not understand:
"Let $X$ be a vector field on a surface with an isolated zero at a point $z$. Construct a small polygon containing $z$ in its interior and having edges transverse to $X$."

What does it means to have edges transverse of $X$ in this case?

Answer (score 1):

In this case transversality just means that the vector field is not tangent to any edge.